# VK Web API (simple)

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, vk

I would like to call the method "photos.get" and retrieve photos from a VK community. The problem is that I am unable to view the oid i.e owner_id( one of the parameters required for the request) when I visit the URL.  For example, when I browse a certain community, I end up getting a URL like "http://vk.com/picsa". Instead of this picsa, I require a number that can be passed in as an argument. How do I get the owner_id instead from the URL?

Comment: did you succceeded? can you share your code? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groups.getById` API method. It does not require any authentication:

https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getById?group_ids=picsa

You will get the default group entity in JSON format:

```
{
    "response": [
        {
            "gid": 37460919, 
            "name": "AMERICA", 
            "screen_name": "picsa", 
            "is_closed": 0, 
            "type": "page", 
            // photos of different size go here
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, you can extract the community's ID (`gid`) and will be able to use it in other API requests. You can get information about several communities at the same time - you need to enumarate them with commas (`/method/groups.getById?group_ids=picsa,othergroup,somename`).

When you work with `photos.get` method, keep in mind, that VK uses **negative** ID values for communities and pages.

For example,
`/method/photos.get?owner_id=123456789` means "photos of user 123456789" and
`/method/photos.get?owner_id=-123456` means "photos of community 123456".

Answer (score 4):

Other way to get group id when there is no it in group link is to click on post date of any post on the wall
[image]

And in the address line you will see link like

```
https://vk.com/picsa?w=wall-37460919_47702
```

So **37460919** is group id you need