# Does VK API support a search by file type?

Tags: vk, vk-sdk

Say I browse to a vk community and would like to be able to retrieve all of the gifs uploaded to that community, How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method [docs.get](https://vk.com/dev/docs.get)

Access it by link

> https://api.vk.com/method/docs.get.xml?owner_id=-**GROUP_ID**&access_token=**YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN**

Read [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912670/spring-social-vk-vkontakte-how-to-fetch-user-photo-albums/31915379#31915379) to know a bit more if you do not have an **acess_token**

In result you will see a document with xml-format. (if you want to use json-response-format just remove "**.xml**" from link you're accessing)

Document will contatin all doc-count and information about each of them like **document_id, its title and size**, **extension** and **url**.

Note that if you accessnig documents from community (not from user) your owner_id in the link must be negative, it must contain **-** before community_id

To know community id you can read [another my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844144/vk-web-api-simple/31915458#31915458)

Feel free to ask any questions if you didn't understand anything :)

Comment: That was extremely helpful and to the point.Thank you! 
I had this one more question.Sometimes, I have to call methods that return a list of "post" objects as per VK API.I use a simple json2csharp converter which gives me the proper classes to deal with the objects returned, but with methods like wall.get, I get the C# object.
From what I know, I have to cast this object type into post, but the post class isn't available and neither is listed when I enter JSON response to a JSON2Csharp converter.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know c#

Comment: Thanks man! You've been mighty helpful.Hope you keep up the good work. :)