# Salesforce and vk.com API integration

Tags: salesforce, integration, vk, salesforce-chatter

I need to implement such functionality, that can allow to manage vk.com* entities (create posts, send messages, add new friends etc) form Salesforce side. Although vk.com provides rich API with good documentation, but I look for already developed solutions for Apex.

I checked AppExchange for it and googled popular solutions, but didn't find anything:( Are there any ready apex ways or have I to do it myself? Maybe I can use power of Salesforce Chatter?

I will be glad to any advice, suggestions!

**vk.com is social network, kind of Facebook, which has a much higher relevance than Facebook in Eastern Europe, especially Russia.*

Comment: I guess you need to do it yourself. I'm from Belarus and know that vk.com not so much famous in countries where SF is actively used and also know that Salesforce is not popular in Eastern Europe. Also I'm not sure that you need to use Apex, look to JS

Comment: @PavelSlepenkov yep, seems, there are no any solutions, I'm looking for. So I'll implement it. But I leave this question here, maybe someone has some ideas

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320591/does-vk-api-support-a-search-by-file-type/32324981#32324981

Comment: @SwiftStudier Seems we talk about different things. I mean some Salesforce solutions for working with vk.com and I know that I can run http requests right from Apex code.